# How to implement the `Index` trait for a simple struct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement the `Index` trait for a simple trait, and I want to use it with `usize`. I added `SliceIndex<[T], Output = T>` so I can use `T` to index the `slice` inside `A`.

```
use std::ops::Index;
use std::slice::SliceIndex;

struct A <'a, T>{
    slice: &'a [T]
}

impl<'a, T: Index<T, Output = T> + SliceIndex<[T], Output = T>> Index<T>
    for A<'a, T>
{
    type Output = T;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn index(&self, index: T) -> &Self::Output {
        self.slice.index(index)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut aa: Vec<u64> = vec![0; 10];
    let coefficient_iterable = A{slice: &aa};
    println!("{}", coefficient_iterable[1usize]);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9564b39061cae3e19db14217c10b9d8a

But I get:

Error:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `A<'_, u64>`
  --> src/main.rs:22:20
   |
22 |     println!("{}", coefficient_iterable[1usize]);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0608`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I have no idea why, since `usize` implements `SliceIndex<[T]>`.

Answer (score 6):

Requiring `T` to be both `Index` and `SliceIndex` doesn't make sense because `Index` describes the behaviour of indexable containers, while `SliceIndex` is a bound you can put on a generic indexing type to make it more flexible.

You don't want to implement `Index<T>` because `T` here is the type of the items in the slice, not the type of the index. For the code in your `main` function to work you could just implement `Index<usize>`, but generically implementing `Index<Idx>` (where `Idx: SliceIndex`) gives more flexibility so you can use ranges too.

```rust
use std::ops::Index;
use std::slice::SliceIndex;

struct A<'a, T> {
    slice: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T, Idx> Index<Idx> for A<'a, T>
where
    Idx: SliceIndex<[T], Output = T>,
{
    type Output = T;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output {
        self.slice.index(index)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let aa: Vec<u64> = vec![0; 10];
    let coefficient_iterable = A { slice: &aa };
    assert_eq!(coefficient_iterable[1], 0);
}
```