# Rust version of Python's __getitem__

Tags: rust

Python has a special class method `__getitem__` that is basically syntactic sugar. For example,

```py
class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.list[key]
```

will allow you to get elements of `MyList` objects like this: `mylist[2]`. I wonder if there is a trait in Rust that does the same kind of thing. Just like the trait `Ord` in Rust allows you to use `>`, `<`, `==`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement the \`Index\` trait for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950635/how-to-implement-the-index-trait-for-a-simple-struct)

Comment: Thanks! This answers the natural follow up question to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) for your struct, which allows you to use the bracket operators to get an *immutable* reference to the data. If you want *mutable* access, you also need [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html)